# Given a linear map $r:\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, how to define a point-derivation?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I try to understand that the tangent space of a manifold is a dual space of ideal quotient i.e. $T_pM\cong (\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2)^*$ where $\mathcal{J}$ is an ideal of smooth functions vanishing at $p\in M$.

I have the forward direction, that is, given a derivation $D\in T_pM$ we can define $r:\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $r=D$. However, I am stuck in the other direction. I have checked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281590/tangent-space-as-the-dual-of-an-ideal-quotient), but have trouble with the backward.

Given a linear map $v:\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, we need to check $Df=v(f-f(p)+I^2)$ defines a derivation at $p$: let $f\sim g\in C^{\infty}$

1. $v(f-f(p)+I^2)=v(g-g(p)+I^2)$
2. Leibniz rule works by the quotient $\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2$ and vanishing property.

$f\sim g$ means $f=g$ on a small neighborhood of $p$, say $W_p$, but $f,g$ only agree on $W_p$ but maybe not others. I am stuck here and also why do we define $Df$ like this?

PS. I am sorry as a beginner in manifold theory if the question seems too trivial.

Comment: It looks like you have the solution here - can you explain how you're stuck?

Comment: @KReiser My question is: 1. given $f,g\in C^{\infty}$ and $f\sim g$ by the equivalence in germs, show that $v(f-f(p)+I^2)=v(g-g(p)+I^2)$.

Comment: $I = \mathcal J$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Are derivations defined for smooth functions on $M$ or for germs of smooth functions around $p$?